# Error al ejecutar una consulta para iniciar sesión con php

Tags: phpmyadmin, login

He estado haciendo un inicio de sesión con datos guardados en una base en phpMyAdmin. Cuando trato de iniciar sesión con un usuario que ya este registrado mi lanza el siguiente error:

*Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com, fld_contra AS 123456789 FROM tbl_clientes WHERE fld_consecutivo a...' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\makip\services\frmlogin.php:41 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\makip\services\frmlogin.php(41): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT fld_emai...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\makip\services\frmlogin.php on line 41*

En ese texto veo que me dice que la sintaxis de la consulta está mal, pero cuando ejecuto la misma consulta en phpMyAdmin, no me lanza ningún error. Para ser honesto, yo soy un principiante, por consiguiente, no entiendo mucho de esto y no soy capaz de ver el error, pero espero que uno de ustedes me pueda ayudar.

En el formulario de conexion.php tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "db_makip";

$conexión = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);

if($conexión->connect_error) {
     die("Conexión falló debido al error: ".$conexion->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Y en el formulario de inicio de sesión tengo lo siguiente:

```
<?php
include('conexion.php'); 

     $pEmail=$_POST['email'];
     $pContra=$_POST['password'];

     $query= "SELECT fld_email AS $pEmail,"; 
     $query .=" fld_contra AS $pContra";
     $query .=" FROM tbl_clientes";
     $query .=" WHERE fld_consecutivo";
          if ($pContra!="") {
          $query .=" and fld_contra=md5('".$pContra."')";
}

$result= mysqli_query($conexion,$query);  // Ejecuta la consulta y el resultado lo almecena en una variable
$NomEmail="";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo($row['fld_email']);
    $NomEmail=$row['fld_email'];
}
if ($NomEmail=="")
{
    echo('*** Usuario No Existe ***');
} else 
{
   if ($pContra!=""){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["NombreUsuario"]=$NomEmail;
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Es muy raro querer usar alias dinámicos. Pero si insistes, intenta así: `$query= "SELECT fld_email AS \"$pEmail\",";`.

Comment: okey. ya no me sale el error, pero aun ingresando un usuario con los datos correctos, este no entra y me dice que no lo encuentra, cuando debería, según mi código, validar la sesión.

Comment: y que es lo que hace WHERE fld_consecutivo, esa condicion siempre se cumple?

Comment: puessss, esa tabla ya la cree hace rato, y no me acuerdo bien para que era, pero si se cumple la ccondición.

Comment: ayuda por favor, estoy atorado en esa parte y no he podido avanzar

Comment: cualquier aporte será agradecido :)